# Why are my audio sounds not playing on time?

Tags: iphone, audio, nstimer, openal

One of my apps has a simple metronome-style feature that plays a click sound a specified number of times per minute (bpm). I'm doing this by starting an NSTimer, with an interval calculated from the specified bpm, that calls a method that plays the sound.

If I put an NSLog line into the play method, I can see that NSTimer is firing accurately to about 1 millisecond. However, if I record the sound output into an audio editor and then measure the interval between clicks, I can see that they are not evenly spaced. For example, with 150 bpm, the timer fires every 400 milliseconds. But most of the sounds play after 395 milliseconds, with every third or fourth sound playing after 418 milliseconds.

So the sounds are not uniformly delayed, but rather, they follow a pattern of shorter and longer intervals. It seems as if the iOS has a lower resolution for timing of sounds, and is rounding each sound event to the nearest available point, rounding up or down as needed to keep on track overall.

I have tried this with system sounds, AVAudioPlayer and OpenAL and have gotten the exact same results with all three methods. With each method, I'm doing all the setup when the view loads, so each time I play the sound all I have to do is play it. With AVAudioPlayer, I tried calling prepareToPlay using a second timer after each time the sound plays, so it is initialized and ready to go next time, but got the same results.

Here's the code for setting up the OpenAL sound in viewDidLoad (adapted from [this tutorial](http://benbritten.com/2008/11/06/openal-sound-on-the-iphone/)):

```
// set up the context and device
ALCcontext *context;
ALCdevice *device;
OSStatus result;
device = alcOpenDevice(NULL); // select the "preferred device"
if (device) {
    context = alcCreateContext(device, NULL); // use the device to make a context
    alcMakeContextCurrent(context); // set the context to the currently active one
}

// open the sound file
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TempoClick" ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AudioFileID fileID;
result = AudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)soundFileURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &fileID);
if (result != 0) DLog(@"cannot open file %@: %ld", soundFilePath, result);

// get the size of the file data
UInt32 fileSize = 0;
UInt32 propSize = sizeof(UInt64);
result = AudioFileGetProperty(fileID, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataByteCount, &propSize, &fileSize);
if (result != 0) DLog(@"cannot find file size: %ld", result);
DLog(@"file size: %li", fileSize);

// copy the data into a buffer, then close the file
unsigned char *outData = malloc(fileSize);
AudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)soundFileURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &fileID); // we get a "file is not open" error on the next line if we don't open this again
result = AudioFileReadBytes(fileID, false, 0, &fileSize, outData);
if (result != 0) NSLog(@"cannot load data: %ld", result);
AudioFileClose(fileID);
alGenBuffers(1, &tempoSoundBuffer);
alBufferData(self.tempoSoundBuffer, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, outData, fileSize, 44100);
free(outData);
outData = NULL;

// connect the buffer to the source and set some preferences
alGenSources(1, &tempoSoundSource); 
alSourcei(tempoSoundSource, AL_BUFFER, tempoSoundBuffer);
alSourcef(tempoSoundSource, AL_PITCH, 1.0f);
alSourcef(tempoSoundSource, AL_GAIN, 1.0f);
alSourcei(tempoSoundSource, AL_LOOPING, AL_FALSE);
```

And then in the play method I just call:

```
alSourcePlay(self.tempoSoundSource);
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here, and how I can work around it?

UPDATE 1:

I have another project that plays brief sounds with audio units, so as a quick test I added a timer to that project to play my click sound every 400 milliseconds. In that case, the timing is nearly perfect. So, it seems that NSTimer is fine but system sounds, AVAudioPlayer and OpenAL are less accurate in their playback than audio units.

UPDATE 2:

I just reworked my project to use audio units and now the audio is playing back much more accurately. It still occasionally drifts by up to four milliseconds in either direction, but this is better than the other audio methods. I'm still curious why the other methods all show a pattern of short, short, short, long intervals -- it's like the audio playback times are being rounded up or down to map to some kind of frame rate -- so I'll leave this question open for anyone who can explain that and/or offer a workaround for the other audio methods.

Comment: not sure but might your NSLog is causing the lag, if it's there

Comment: @Ahmed: That's a good thought, but I just commented out the NSLog and got the same results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to program a real-time accurate audio sequencer on the iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907137/how-to-program-a-real-time-accurate-audio-sequencer-on-the-iphone)

Comment: Could you post the code for your OpenAL test? Specifically the population of the buffer and queuing onto the source. Are you perhaps repeatedly creating the buffer rather than using AL_LOOPING?

Comment: @RJFalconer: I just added my code above. I'm doing all the setup once and only calling the play method when the timer fires. But perhaps I've set something up incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've figured it out. The real reason audio units worked better than the other audio methods is that my audio unit class, which I was adapting from another project, was setting a buffer duration property in the audio session, like this:

```
Float32 preferredBufferSize = .001;
UInt32 size = sizeof(preferredBufferSize);
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration, size, &preferredBufferSize);
```

When I added this code to the OpenAL version, or even to the AVAudioPlayer version, I got accuracy to within a few milliseconds, the same as with audio units. (System Sounds, however, were still not very accurate.) I can verify the connection by increasing the buffer size and watching the playback intervals get less accurate.

Of course I only figured this out after spending an entire day adapting my project to use audio units -- tweaking it to compile under C++, testing the interruption handlers, etc. I hope this can save someone else from the same trouble.

Answer (score 1):

NSTimer does not guarantee when your method will actually get fired.

More info here: [How to program a real-time accurate audio sequencer on the iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907137/how-to-program-a-real-time-accurate-audio-sequencer-on-the-iphone)

Regarding your edits:

AVAudioPlayer takes some time to initialize itself. If you call prepareToPlay, it will initialize itself such that it can play the currently loaded sound immediately upon calling play. Once playback stops, it uninitializes itself, so you'd need to call prepareToPlay again to reinitialize. It's best to use this class for stream-y playback rather than discrete sound playback.

With OpenAL, once you've loaded the buffer, attaching it to a source and playing it should cause no delay at all.

You can encapsulate your audio units code into a .mm file and then call that from .m modules without having to compile those as C++.

Comment: According to the timestamps on my NSLogs, the method is getting fired to the nearest millisecond, which is close enough for my purposes. The link above focuses on making a more accurate timer, but it seems in my case that the timer is not the problem.

Comment: "You can encapsulate your audio units code into a .mm file and then call that from .m modules without having to compile those as C++." Are you sure about that? I couldn't get that to work. If you can clarify, I've posted a separate question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944465/how-can-i-use-a-few-c-files-in-my-project-without-compiling-every-file-as-c