# How can I use a few C++ files in my project without compiling every file as C++?

Tags: iphone, c++, ios, xcode, compiler-construction

I have a project with a base view controller class, that is inherited by about 25 other view controllers. Now I need to use a bit of core audio in that base class, so I'm integrating an Audio class (adapted from Apple's aurioTouch example project) that uses C++. The base class imports the Audio class's header, and then initializes an Audio object so that I can call methods within the Audio class.

When I compile, I get errors like "expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '!=' token" in the Audio class and its helper classes, because the compiler is tripping over the C++ syntax. If I change the extension of the base class to .mm I get the same errors; I think I will have to also change the extension of all the classes that inherit from the base class.

Is there a way to avoid this? In other words, how can I compile just the minimum amount of files as C++ -- ideally just the Audio class, or the Audio class and the base class -- without changing the rest of the project?

The reason I ask is that this bit of audio is about .5% of the app's functionality, and it seems wrong to change dozens of files to compile differently just because of this one small addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should actually suffice to rename the `.m` file that uses C++ functionality to `.mm`. You have to make sure that you don't include any C++ headers in the header file of your class, otherwise the other non-C++ classes will go berserk trying to include your class's header file.

Comment: Okay, I was importing the Audio class from the base class's header ... I just added a forward declaration instead and moved the import to the base class's implementation file. Is that what you would recommend? That seems to have solved it -- but it triggered a handful of different errors that are now popping up with the change in compilation language -- so I'll work on those now and then see if I can compile. The errors are now only in the base class, so I think I'm on the right track.

Comment: That's going into the right direction. But simply a forward declaration won't work, since that - again - is C++ code which the other files won't understand. So the only possibility that's left is having a pointer to your class that is of a type normal C will accept. If I remember correctly, I resolved this issue by creating some anonymous struct forward declaration and used that in the header: `struct MyClass * myClassPointer;`. Maybe that helps?

Comment: Actually, it worked fine to put a forward declaration in the base class's header, and import the Audio class's header in the base class's implementation file. I had to fix a few other errors that popped up due to the slightly different compilation rules of C++, but now everything is compiling and running. Would another alternative be to create a C wrapper class for the C++ class? I'll explore that later, but this is good for now. Thanks!